# What set are these blue, purple, and green pieces from?

Tags: set-identification

[image: a sealed bag of LEGO bricks]

I found a bag of LEGO bricks and I want to know from what set this is.

I tried searching on brickset.com. But they can't find the set.

It contains:

- Plate round 6x6 medium azure 11213
- Plate 6 x 12 green 4541414
- brick 2x4 purple (2 pieces)
- flower 4143562 (2 pieces)

I hope you can help me.

Comment: thank you I will try then website now!

Comment: Hi Coolen and welcome to Bricks.SE! Let us know if you have any issues with the site, we're here to help if you get stuck.

Comment: this refers to set "10692-1" on my BL results.